# Cakephp Migration: Two Auth types using Security and Auth Component

Tags: security, cakephp, authentication, migration

I just migrated my application from Cake 1.3 to 2.4.4 and I'm not able to solve following issue:

In my application, users need to authenticate (with a unique user + password known only by the community) before they are able to register their personnal account.

In version 1.3 that was quite simple using both security an auth component:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
var $components = array('Auth', 'Security');

function beforeFilter() {                       
    // Used for 
    $this->Security->loginOptions = array('type'=>'basic');            
    $this->Security->loginUsers = array(
        'sampleUser' => 'smaplePassword' // same user + PW for all users
    );
    $this->Security->requireLogin();

    // Used for specific user login
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'); 
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Game', 'action' => 'index'); 
    $this->Auth->loginError = "Benutzername und/oder Passwort falsch!";
    $this->Auth->authError = "Keine Berechtigung, bitte einloggen!";
}
```

}

Now in version 2, security component has been migrated to auth. I tried hard to find a solution but was not able to come up with something until now.

Is it even possible to do this using cake 2.4.4?

Comment: That doesn't look very secure to me. Why not using the approach everyone else does and let each other decide on its own password? But the answer is: yes, it is possible. Even easier than in any version before. Simply create your own custom Auth adapter with that hardcoded login check.

Comment: Reason is that not everybody should be able to access the website in the first place (testing period is still ongoing). So only people who know the unique user + pw are able to access the webiste and register a personal account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Security Component, but you could use the Auth Component for logins in CakePHP 1.3 anyway.

I suggest you first convert the logins to be via the Auth component in v1.3 and then migrate from there.

Take a look at my [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443855/cakephp-upgrade-from-1-3-to-2-authentication-failure/35443856#35443856) for migrating CakePHP authentication from 1.3 - 2.x.