# cakephp upgrade from 1.3 to 2 authentication failure

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I've actually figured this out but I couldn't find anything about this until brainstorming with another developer - tracing through the core code to figure out what was going on.

**The problem is quite simple - after upgrading from CakePHP v1.3 to v2.5.9 the login (authentication) doesn't work. But there is no error message to tell you why it's not working.**

As is noted in the [2.0 Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#authcomponent):

> The AuthComponent was entirely re-factored for 2.0, this was done to help reduce developer confusion and frustration. In addition, AuthComponent was made more flexible and extensible. You can find out more in the [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) guide.

The Authentication guide mentioned explains all well and good how you should get it to work for a new installation but nothing about what you need to do to migrate.

The further problem is that there is no error to tell you what is going on.

I copied the code for the `UsersController.php -> login` method from the Authentication guide section on [Identifying users](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in):

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Important: Use login() without arguments! See warning below.
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            // Prior to 2.3 use
            // `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default',
            array(),
            'auth'
        );
    }
}
```

In my `AppController.php` I had the following:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session', 'P28n', 'Store', 'SiteStore', 'UserAccessLevel', 'Auth'
);
```

Then in `AppController.php -> beforeFilter`:

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
$this->Auth->loginError = __('Login failed, invalid username or password. Please try again.');
$this->Auth->authError = __('Please log-in.');
$this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout');
```

The only thing for sure that I knew is that `$this->Auth->login()` is returning false. But the problem could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was hashing of passwords.** Easy once you know the answer.

I'd got as far as adding in the Simple password hashing component [suggested in the Authentication guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords):

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But this still failed, but I couldn't confirm that password hashing was definitely the cause. It took tracing the code through to `BaseAuthenticate::_findUser` that was definitely failing on the passwords to confirm it.

At this point I then made a stab that the hashing of the passwords from CakePHP could be made to match the Simple passwordHasher.

The passwords in CakePHP 1.3 are saved using sha1, and switching `'hashType' => 'sha1'` fixed the problem:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha1'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```